# MVC4 ModelState Validation and Required Parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, modelstate

I have a Model called "Publication", which has another Model inside it called "Publisher":

```
public class Publication
{
    public int PublicationID { get; set; }
    public Publisher Publisher { get; set; }
}

public class Publisher
{
    public int PublisherID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

So when I get the Publications' data from the database, I also fill the Publisher info for each Publication to work with it if needed.

When I add another Publication, I have to chose a Publisher, it's an obligatory field, and I have a DropDownList in the page containing all Publishers so the user can choose which Publisher for that Publication:

```
<div>
    @HtmlDropDownListFor(model => model.Publisher.PublisherID, myPublisherList)
</div>
```

And it's filling the data perfectly fine, but I'm getting an error in the line:

```
if(ModelState.IsValid)
```

Because the Publisher's Name haven't been specified, even though I only need the ID.
I don't want to drop the Model.IsValid line because there's a bunch of other fields that require validation, and I'd like to leave it as clean as possible, so is there an easy way to fill the name value of it?

I thought of adding a Hidden Field and using Javascript to fill the value every time the user changes the Select, but I'd like to use a cleaner and javascript-free approach if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I use different models with the same property names and structures due to this.

For the view:

```
public class PublicationViewModel
{
    public int PublicationID { get; set; }
    public PublisherViewModel Publisher { get; set; }
}

public class PublisherViewModel
{
    public int PublisherID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

On the action:

```
public class PublicationActionModel
{
    public int PublicationID { get; set; }
    public PublisherActionModel Publisher { get; set; }
}

public class PublisherActionModel
{
    public int PublisherID { get; set; }
}
```